# How to find the relative path of an image tag with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I go through many problems regarding this, but couldn't find a clear answer.
I have an image tag like this:

```
<img src="images/abc.jpg"/>
```

But when I called in side javascript,

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
alert(imgs[0].src);
```

it shows the "src" as "http://localhost/myProject/images/abc.jpg", but I need to get only the relative path ("images/abc.jpg") somehow.
Somebody help me...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may try to get the element `src` attribute value, not the `src` property:

```
imgs[0].getAttribute("src");  // "images/abc.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.location.href` to split out the relative path of the image.